# FETCH_ASSOC and SELECT * FROM two tables with the same column name

Tags: mysql, wildcard, resultset

I have lot of MySQL tables with the same column name. So Im looking for PDO or SQL hack for SELECT * FROM more tables - which will return table names in result sets.

Example:

`'SELECT * FROM table0, table1';`

Where both tables has 'name' column. But FETCH_ASSOC result returns only one 'name' - the last one.

Result:

```
echo $result["name"];
```

Wanted result:

```
echo $result["table0.name"];
echo $result["table1.name"];
...
```

Note that

1. I cannot rename DB columns to be unique
2. I cannot manualy create alias for each columns (lot of tables/columns)
3. I want name in result set not numbers like FETCH_NUM

Any ideas? 
Thanks!

Comment: What is exactly wrong with doing two queries, one for each individual table?

Comment: Looking for the same issue solution.

Answer (score 1):

Hack doesn't exist, you have to create aliases.

Answer (score 1):

You said that you don't want to alias all columns because there are too many, but have you considered only aliasing the ones that give you problems?

```
SELECT
    *, 
    table0.name AS t0name,
    table1.name AS t1name
FROM table0 JOIN table1 ON ...
```

Comment: Thanks for partial suggestion. I have found another. FETCH_NAMED returns problematic columns as numbered array and other as ordinary scalars. 

[unique] => val
[name] => Array(
      [0] => val
      [1] => val
      )

One way is to format result set with php.